# South Africa - Helping a layman with connecting multiple strings of lights on one plug

Tags: transformer, light

How would I connect 10 x light strings (20 lamps x 3v/0.06w) to one plug the transformers that come with the light sets are
Input: 230-240Va.c 50Hz
Output: 24Vac 6va

Can I just get a bigger transformer and join the cables...? can the existing transformers handle connecting 2 together..

Any help would be awesome :D My electrical experience is i can change a plug :D

Comment: Do you mean 200 lights? (20 lamps/string x 10 strings) or 20 total or ..? | IF there are 20 lamps in the string how are they connected? - all in series (20 x 3V = 60V) or ...? | If 20 lamps per string and made for 24VAC then they may be 2 x (10 lamps x 3V) = 30V nominal fed with 24 VAC. Or ...? | Please provide enough information so that it is clear to we afar off who cannot see what you see what it is that you are seeing. || All Blacks!!! :-) - guess my country ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your lamps are 0.18VA  your strings each are 3.6VA for 10 strings you need a 36VA, or larger, transformer

You could connect several smaller transformers in parallel if they are well matched.